# Date format parsing using Now()

Tags: vb.net

I need to compare dates in winforms, using vb.net
I am trying using

```
If Now() = DateTime.Parse("17.01.2013 08:47:10 PM")
```

The problem is my date is in dd/mm/yyyy format but when this application runs on a system where the format is mm/dd/yy, it gives problem.

How can I bring the system date (obtained using NOW()) in dd/mm/yyyy format so it could be compared with my given date?

Thanks

Comment: try to format your dates with the same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DateTime.ParseExact` or `TryParseExact`:

```
Dim date As Datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(_
    "17.01.2013 08:47:10 PM", "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
if (Now().ToString("MM/dd/yy") = myDate)
```

Careful of "MM" and "mm" in vb formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" as this works with any dateformat and also with SQL. See below:

```
Private Shared Sub DateCompare()

    Dim myDate As Date = "12/07/2013 21:31:34"

    Dim nowDateString As String = Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    Dim myDateString As String = Format(myDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

    If nowDateString = myDateString Then
        MessageBox.Show("Matches")
    End If

End Sub
```